# Router and Gateway different

Tags: router, gateway

This may be simple, but it's driving me up the wall.

**My Setup**
I have a TechoWiFi dish to connect to a wireless mast
That goes into a router NetGear JWNR2010v5
My PCs connect physically to the router (address is 192.168.1.1)
My ISP gave me a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and a gateway of 192.168.0.254
I have set my router to point to these addresses.

Now, to connect to the internet, I have to set my PC addresses manually using the ISP supplied gateway, and everything works fine.
But, I can't connect to my router.
If I use my router as the gateway, I can't connect to the internet.

If you're curious, the reason I'm trying to access my router is that using the ISP supplied router, I suffered continuous dropouts (up to 100 a day). The other PCs in the house didn't seem to have this problem, so I figured it must b my PC. But I can't find anything that seems to be a pattern. 
I've tried wired and WiFi and I've tried using a USB WiFi dongle to eliminate the card.

I wanted to look at the router logs to see if there was anything being reported but I couldn't access it. Therefore, I attached my own router. But I seem to be in the same situation as before.
The only events showing in Windows are "unable to connect to DNS servers"

Any help in either my main question or my underlying problem would be very gratefully received.

Comment: Have you put your ISP's DNS into your router so it knows how to route requests?

Comment: Could you clarify (perhaps with a diagram)? Your router's external address is in the `192.168.0.x/24` subnet, and your ISP hosts a gateway at `192.168.0.254`? Your router's internal address is `192.168.1.1` and Your computers get addresses from the router - e.g: `192.168.1.x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to connect to the internet, I have to set my PC addresses manually using the ISP supplied gateway

Based on the fact that your PCs can directly reach the ISP's gateway address, it sounds like you've connected the uplink (cable from TechoWiFi) to the wrong port on your Netgear. The described situation can only happen if both connections are bridged and bypass the routing – e.g. if you connected the uplink to a 'LAN' port.

According to pictures I found, it should be connected to the blue 'Internet' port, which is separately routed.

> If I use my router as the gateway, I can't connect to the internet.

This just reinforces my guess that you've connected the uplink device to the wrong port on the Netgear. Even though the Netgear knows the correct gateway address, it will be trying to reach it specifically through the 'Internet' port.

It's also *possible*, although probably unlikely, that the Netgear is configured via firmware to act as a bridge on *all* ports. (Perhaps you switched it to access-point mode? In this situation you do in fact want to switch it back to full 'router' mode.)